# Is ことが大きい a synonym of による所が大きい?

Tags: grammar

This is a question from 日本城郭検定 in 2015:

> 今回の指定は、城が完成した年を裏付ける祈祷札の**再発見による所が大きい**。この祈祷札に書かれていた年号はどれか。

And this is the same question in 2017 edition of the test:

> 2015年の松江城の国宝指定は、城の完成した年を裏付ける祈祷札が**再発見されたことが大きい**。祈祷札に書かれていた年号はどれか。

i am perfectly fine with the first question: "the designation was largely influenced by the discovery ...", however I cannot make sense of what happened in the latter form.

Is it a simple mistake (i.e. it should be in fact 再発見されたことによる所が大きい), or does the latter question make sense?

And if it is correct and makes sense, why?

By "**why**" I mean: please provide references or examples of the usage of this form. I can't find any.

Comment: I think the former one the designation is largely contributed by... and the latter one is largely backed up by... I think the both are same meaning.In my opinion, the former one is a little bit more formal.

Comment: But though many grammar resources and dictionaries list による所が大きい, I can't find a single one with ことが大きい example. I'm grateful for your opinion, but some backing would be 大きい to make it trustworthy ;)

Comment: Me neither. I think it comes from 大事: important. So, the discovery was important.

Answer (score 1):

The latter sentence also makes sense perfectly to me. The second sentence merely paraphrased the first sentence. It would be easier for you to understand if you paraphrase 指定は to 指定には.

> 指定は、**祈祷札の再発見**による所が大きい。

The designation was largely influenced by/contributed by/due to the discovery of the 祈祷札."

> 指定(に）は、**祈祷札が再発見された**ことが大きい。

To have been discovered the 祈祷札　is **a big thing/point** regarding the designation.

This is merely my guess, but the writer basically just wanted to edit 今回の指定 to 2015年の指定, but as he was proceeding to type, he just typed 祈祷札が instead of 祈祷札の. So he had to change the noun 再発見 to the verb 再発見された, and had to change the rest of the part as well.

> 指定は、**祈祷札が再発見された**ことによる所が大きい。

This is also grammatically correct, but it seems redundant. So he would have choose the shorter version.

If you search Google, entering ["ことが大きい。"], you can get a lot of sentences to use it. This is the evidence that native speakers use this expression, although you don't think it is correct because there is no explanation by dictionaries.

In my opinion, ことが大きい may be a little childish than 寄与している所が大きい or some other "sophisticated" expressions, but it's simple and fundamental, jut like "**a big thin**g" in English.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I specifically tagged the question with [tag:grammar] and asked **why** was the sentence correct. Not what it meant. There is no doubt about it.

Comment: Okay. I will make another answer for the grammar. :)

Answer (score 1):

The second example is correct, too.

The first example includes an expression that clearly stands for causal relationship between the "re-discovery" and the "designation" i.e 再発見によるところ.

On the other hand, the second one apparently lacks it. However, it's natural for the こと as in 再発見されたこと, especially combined with が大きい, to be interpreted as a "factor" rather than a mere "thing". In other words, 再発見されたことが大きい can be translated into "the fact that it was re-discovered was big" or "it being re-discovered was a major factor".

Comment: Shouldn't then it be connected  to 指定 with ～に, ～のため, or else, indicating purpose? Is the grammar in the second example unambiguous that it was the discovery contributing to the designation, not that it was discovered while in the process of registration?

Comment: You can use either 指定は or 指定には but not 指定に or 指定のため, which would make the sentence topicless. As long as you don't consider the first sentence ambiguous, so is the second, because they are synonymous.